# Generate parameters for pdftk with loop in bash

Tags: bash, command-line, pdftk

I want to generate a list of file names containing n=1 to k, add the string "cat output xyz.pdf" at its end and pass the result as parameter to `pdftk`. It should execute as this:

```
pdftk file1.pdf file2.pdf file3.pdf cat output xyz.pdf
```

How can I automate this directly in the CLI?

Comment: Is `k` a fixed integer - or a shell variable?

Comment: A fixed integer. @steeldriver

Comment: By now you already know the answer but as a bonus you don't even need `pdftk` to merge files. `pdfunite` is part of `poppler` and installed by default in most distros. `pdfunite file{1..k}.pdf xyz.pdf`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using bash as indicated by your question tag, there's no need for a loop: you should be able to use *brace expansion*.

Ex. for k = 32

```
pdftk file{1..32}.pdf cat output xyz.pdf
```

If the number of files is *very* large, this approach may become limited by `ARG_MAX` (resulting in an "argument list too long" error).

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might be what you're after:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

filelist=""

for i in {1..5}; do
    filelist+="file${i}.pdf "
done

pkftk ${filelist} cat output xyz.pdf
```

The loop runs from 1..k and builds a string containing "file1.pdf ... filek.pdf".  After the loop finishes, it runs `pdftk` passing the file list as well as the "cat output xyz.pdf" that you specified in your question.

If you want a one-liner, you can condense the above to (here assuming `k=5`):

```
pdftk $(for i in {1..5}; do printf "%s " file$i.pdf; done) cat output.xyz.pdf
```

The logic is the same, but I use command substitution to run the `for` loop; the `$(...)` is replaced with the output of `...` (in this case, the file list).  I use `printf` instead of `echo` as a way to avoid newlines.

Comment: I'd like to do it in one line, without saving a script first, if possible?

Comment: But it works. Thank you!